# Grouping Data by Search Algorithms

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, search

I have a sample dataset in Python, where each piece of data has 3 values:

[ String Date,   Integer 24hr Time (first two numbers = hours, last two numbers = minutes),   Integer Duration (always 15 minutes) ]

**My goal is to group pieces of data with the same date, which have adjacent 24hr times**. The 24hr time values are separated by a 15 minute interval at adjacency. Ultimately, grouping pieces of data with adjacent times will cause the duration to increase by however many 15 minute intervals were grouped. I've provided the list `final_dataset` below to better represent what the final dataset should look like.

I've tested some code to search through `initial_dataset` on a linear basis. Here is the rough pseudocode:

```
# -- Start at first data piece (call this previous)
    # -- Check next data piece (call this current)
    # -- Subtract 24hr time values for current and previous
    # -- If difference is 15, append to a separate list the combined data piece
         # Check next data piece (call this next)
         # Subtract 24hr time values for next and current
         # Repeat
                  # Check next data piece (call this next next)
                  # Repeat this linear iteration until the difference > 15
                  # Store last position of no adjacency
# -- Continue at the last position of no adjacency and repeat this entire process until end of initial_dataset is reached
```

**By way of data structures or search algorithms, is there a more efficient method of achieving this goal?**

```
# -- Example Dataset
initial_dataset = [ ['July 26, 2021',  1000,  15],
                    ['July 26, 2021',  1015,  15],
                    ['July 26, 2021',  1030,  15],
                    ['July 26, 2021',  1045,  15],
                    ['July 26, 2021',  1500,  15],
                    ['July 27, 2021',  1400,  15], ]

final_dataset = [ ['July 26, 2021', 1000, 60], 
                  ['July 26, 2021', 1500, 15]
                  ['July 27, 2021', 1400, 15] ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `collections.defaultdict`, only a single pass is needed over your data when grouping:

```
import collections
data = [['July 26, 2021', 1000, 15], ['July 26, 2021', 1015, 15], ['July 26, 2021', 1030, 15], ['July 26, 2021', 1045, 15], ['July 26, 2021', 1500, 15], ['July 27, 2021', 1400, 15]]
d = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for a, b, c in data:
   if (v:=int(b/100)) in d[a]:
      d[a][v] += c
   else:
      d[a][v] = c

result = [[a, j*100, k] for a, b in d.items() for j, k in b.items()]
```

Output:

```
[['July 26, 2021', 1000, 60], ['July 26, 2021', 1500, 15], ['July 27, 2021', 1400, 15]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to not strictly group by multiplies of 100 for the 24hr time? Instead by different values every time, depending on the how many adjacent 24hr times there are?

For instance, allowing the grouping of  ['July 26, 2021', 1000, 75]?